# Unable to run Haskell on OSX due to Zsh

Tags: haskell, zsh

I just started learning Haskell and installed GHC-7.8.4 on my OSX 10.10.2 machine. But on on launching GHC im getting the following error. I use Zsh as my default shell. Any way to fix this ?

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending to `~/.bash_profile`, instead append (add to the end) of your `~/.zshrc` file. Then open a new shell (i.e. new Terminal window) and your environment variables will be set appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ava. I had tried doing this, but unfortunately still getting the same error. Is there some other solution ?

Comment: @Jim don't forget to run `source ~/.zshrc` after changing your `.zshrc` file.